# Detecting whether a PDF contains two identical images

Tags: pdf, images

I am looking for a program that can detect whether a PDF contains two identical images.  If possible, Windows 7, free, and can process several PDFs at once.

Even better: the program could take several PDFs as input, and outputs a list of all images contained in all PDFs, along with the number of time the image appears in each PDF (i.e. the output would be a matrix with images as rows and PDFs as columns).

---

Use case: [“This situation left me ashamed and infuriated with myself:” Scientist retracts two papers](http://retractionwatch.com/2014/10/17/this-situation-left-me-ashamed-and-infuriated-with-myself-scientist-retracts-two-papers/)

> Figure 8 contains duplicated images as well as images previously
>   published in articles in Microbiology and Microbial Pathogenesis,
>   i.e., the following:
>
> - S. A. Sousa, C. G. Ramos, L. M. Moreira, and J. H. Leitão,
>     Microbiology 156:896–908, 2010.
>     http://dx.doi.org/10.1099/mic.0.035139-0.
> - C. G. Ramos, S. A. Sousa, A. M. Grilo, L. Eberl, and J. H. Leitão,
>     Microb. Pathog. 48:168–177, 2010.
>     http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.micpath.2010.02.006.